# Drawing One Component Over Another In Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am new to angular.I have two components,One to Display an image slider and another for displaying the list of categories (similar to side nav,but displayed as a list).I want my list component to draw over the image slider so that both are visible, with the image slider's content under list is hidden.
Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Please have a look at this:[Layout Of Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Ipj.png)

```
      <mat-nav-list>
          <a mat-list-item routerLink="#" *ngFor="let list of lists"> 
            <mat-icon >
                {{list.category_icon}}
            </mat-icon>
           {{list.category_name}} 
          </a>
      </mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: share your code for reference